# VBA: Using Array Formula

Tags: vba, array-formulas

I want to find a row number based on two criteria, in column C and E. My data looks like this:

[image]

I have googled my problem and using the `Match` function as an array formula works for this (worked when I used it in Excel, not VBA), but I can't figure out how to make it an array formula in VBA. Different solutions, be it using "[]" or `.Evaluate` didn't work for me (maybe that was my mistake, though). So how would I modify this code to get the result I want:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim rowDB As Long
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet
    
    Set wsDB = ActiveSheet
    rowDB = WorksheetFunction.Match(CDate("30.06.2020") & "EX0500-0001", wsDB.Range("C7:C366") & wsDB.Range("E7:E366"))
End Sub
```

The error I get is "error 13: type mismatch", so I'm not sure if there's another issue here or just the lack of an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

I played with this for a bit and found several problems:

It seems that CDate() doesn't like "30.06.2020" as input and gets a type error. It seems to be happy with "30-06-2020" so maybe use that format instead or just search for string "30.06.2020" instead? This should be ok as long as all of the date formats are consistent.

The [WorksheetFunction.Match()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) second parameter must be a contiguous range and yours is not. Also I don't think the expression `wsDB.Range("C7:C366") & wsDB.Range("E7:E366")` makes sense; if you want to combine ranges use the [Union()](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/join-multiple-ranges/) function. But this will not work here because as mentioned the range is not contigous.

I don't think it is possible to use WorksheetFunction.Match() to search for multiple values, so you might have to search for the date in coulmn C and the string in column E separately.

Here is some vba I got working for just searching for one value:

```
Sub Test4()
    Dim rowDB As Long
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet

    Set wsDB = ActiveSheet
    rowDB = WorksheetFunction.Match("30.06.2020", wsDB.Range("C7:C366"))
    Debug.Print rowDB
End Sub
```

Also, If a match is not found, it will get a "Application-defined or object-defined error" so you will need to implement some error handling.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I'm not sure about the VBA function, but in Excel you can use `Match`with multiple criteria: in my German Excel version, `=VERGLEICH(DATWERT("30.06.2020") & "EX0500-0001"; C7:C366 & E7:E366;0)` works for me, which in the English version should be `=MATCH(DATVALUE("30.06.2020") & "EX0500-0001", C7:C366 & E7:E366,0)`

As for looking separately through the columsn: would that mean two For-Each-Loops? Both columns have duplicate values, e.g. EX0500-0001 for more than one date, so something like `.Find()` wouldn't help, right?

Comment: I was messing around with this some more, as for CDate(): it appears that I was getting the type error due to the regional date format of windows. When I changed it to D-M-Y it worked ok. I could not get the excel formula to work for me, I don't know why. As for the vba: use a For loop to check each cell in the C column to see if it matches the date value, if you find a match for that row, then check if the value in the E column matches your other value: if it matches then you are done, if not check next cell in C column, etc...